# Asus AM602 Modem (cant change setting)

Tags: adsl, modem

Hi I have a DSL modem (Asus AM602 ) but when I want to connect my modem (192.168.1.1)
it said :

```
internet explorer could not open the search page
```

I 99% sure that my modem ip was 192.168.1.1.
any one know what's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

some hints

you are using a proxy, check preferences

try resetting the modem (usually these modems are reset to factory-default 192.168.1.1)

check if YOUR ip settings are matching 192.168.1.0/255.255.255.0

check link between modem and you (cross or straight ethernet cable are you using?)

an *ipconfig /all* would help clearing up some of your problems

Comment: i set ip manualy (192.168.0.2)
and then can ping my modem